# Light stopped rendering but visible in shading viewport - What happened?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

A light that would previously render without any issue suddenly stopped. It has the same exact nodes as the first light and the only difference is the color which wasn't an issue before so I don't see why it should be one now. Does anyone know what could have happened? [image]

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to share you blend file for someone to help you figure this out.

Comment: Is it possible to send you a link to the file in private and then post the solution here?

Comment: Save the blend file with a new name. Start removing objects a few at a time and see if the light comes back. If you get down to the single non-rendering light and a single object to catch that light and still have the error you will have a blend file you should be able to safely share in public?

Comment: I have uploaded a stripped down blender file https://mega.nz/file/7LwCySAB#isXGprskZbLP4KnLNuNHcbI279s6FnLcsj8Vydm_sio
Thank you for helping!

Comment: I don't have a mega.nz account, try https://pasteall.org/blend/ ?

Comment: I found out why it wasn't rendering. There was a keyframe! I don't know how it was made as I didn't animate anything but I deleted it and it render now!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Light is off in Render]

Make sure you didn't turn the light of in the Render by looking at it in the Outliner.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did check that as it has happened before but this time, it is on!